# How to know the maximum input voltage a diode can handle

Tags: diodes

I would like to know the maximum input voltage a diode can handle, I am choosing diodes for circuit and i have noticed that datasheets of diodes such as the [PMEG6020](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMEG6020ER.pdf). Does not really say the maximum input voltage the diode can handle. So does it mean that theoretically i can use any voltage as long as it above the forward voltage and is within current limits?

Comment: If you try to increase the forward voltage across the diode above the datasheet value, you'll find the current increases VERY FAST : tere are clear limits on it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The datasheet] does not really say the maximum input voltage the diode can handle.

It really does.

[image]

*Figure 1. The reverse voltage is specified at 60 V maximum.*

> So does it mean that theoretically I can use any voltage as long as it above the forward voltage and is within current limits?

If it is only ever biased forward then yes, but then why would you need a diode at all?

If it is reverse biased then 60 V is the maximum that should be applied.

Comment: by maximum input voltage  i did mean forward biased.

Comment: *by maximum input voltage i did mean forward biased* If you ask an EE about voltages across a diode you get the "reverse voltage" as the answer. That's because we never apply a voltage across a diode when it is in forward as the current would **increase out of control**. If that's unclear to you then study how diodes behave.

Comment: @Jakequin: Thank you for accepting my answer. Can you add a circuit that you're considering into your question and we'll comment on that.